# Need to have symbol 1 & 2 from a single LineString layer show above/below a MultiPolygon layer using QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, quickosm

Layers are LineString and MultiPolygon obtained using QuickOSM

LineString contains Rule-based symbology:
"wires"='single'
"waterway"='river'

MultiPolygon Contains Rule-based symbology:
"natural"='water'

I would like to have the "river" below the "water" but I need to keep the "wires" above the "water". Please help me out.

Project Info:

Layers are in the same CRS (EPSG:4326).

QGIS Version 3.28.9

LineString layer
[image: LineString]
MultiPolygon layer
[image: MultiPolygon]

Using Matt's solution, the river disappears over the water shape when I pan the map, but only for a moment or two, then it reappears.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to duplicating the layer could be to use a Geometry Generator expression for the river's symbol.

```sql
difference(
    @geometry,      -- the @ prefix works only in recent versions of QGIS, if it causes an error use $geometry
    aggregate( 
        'water',    -- the layer name (or layer id) of the MultiPolygon layer
        'collect',  -- the aggregate name (from the help panel: Returns the multipart geometry of aggregated geometries from an expression)
        @geometry   -- the @ prefix works only in recent versions 
    )
)
```

*Note: The expression relies on both layers having the same Coordinate Reference System. If they are different, the **transform** function will needed to be added to one of the geometries*

e.g.

```sql
difference(
    @geometry,
    transform(           -- example transformation from 3857 to 4326
        aggregate(
            'water', 
            'collect', 
            @geometry
        ),
    'EPSG:3857',
    'EPSG:4326'
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for the answer! I tried your solution but could not get it to work.  'water' in the expression should be the symbol laber (name) or the multipolygon layer name?

Comment: I added some clarification. Let me know if you are still struggling with it.

Comment: When I do this the river symbol disappears over the multipolygon shape when I pan the map around then it reappears after a second or two. This did not happen before, so I'm sure it's due to the geometry generator. I also tried changing the water layer to a single symbol instead of rule-based, but I get the same results. I'll edit my question in a moment to show images

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS you can control the drawing order at the layer level but each layer are fully drawn respecting the layer order (to be more clear that mean that for the line layer you may choose to have the river on top or below the wires but the full line layer has to be either on top or below the polygon layer).

The solution to your problem is to duplicate the line layer (on the layer panel right click on the layer and select duplicate, this will display the layer a second time but it will NOT duplicate the underlying data) then use one layer to display only wires and the second to display only river. You can then order the layer as you like.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I figured as much, but I don't want to believe there isn't an alternative solution than duplicating layers...

Comment: unfortunately I'm not aware of any other solution (note that the layer is not really duplicated, just displayed two time with different settings...)